# How to keep and remove columns with certain condition simultaneously

Tags: r, sapply

I have 8 columns of variables which I must keep column 1 to 3. For column 4 to 8 I need to keep those with only 3 levels and drop which does not qualify that condition.

I tried the following command

```
data3 <- data2[,sapply(data2,function(col)length(unique(col)))==3]
```

It managed to retain the variables with 3 levels, but deleted my first 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a two step process:

```
data4 <- data2[1:3]
#Your answer for the second part here:
data3 <- data2[,sapply(data2,function(col)length(unique(col)))==3]
merge(data3,data4)
```

Depending on what you would like your expected output to be, could try with the option `all =TRUE` inside the `merge()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach:

```
x = 1:3
cbind(data2[x], Filter(function(i) length(unique(i))==3, data2[-x]))

#   1  2  3 5
#1  a  1  3 b
#2  b  2  4 b
#3  c  3  5 b
#4  d  4  6 a
#5  e  5  7 c
#6  f  6  8 c
#7  g  7  9 c
#8  h  8 10 a
#9  i  9 11 c
#10 j 10 12 b
```

**Data:**

```
data2 = setNames(
          data.frame(letters[1:10], 
                     1:10, 
                     3:12, 
                     sample(letters[1:10],10, replace=T),
                     sample(letters[1:3],10, replace=T)),
          1:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns 4:8 are `factor` class, we can also use `nlevels` to `filter` the columns.  We create 'toKeep' as the numeric index of columns to keep, and 'toFilter' as numeric index of columns to `filter`.  We subset the dataset into two: 1) using the 'toKeep' as the index (`data2[toKeep]`), 2) using the 'toFilter', we further subset the dataset by looping with `sapply` to find the number of levels (`nlevels`), create logical index (`==3`) to `filter` the columns and `cbind` with the first subset.

```
toKeep <- 1:3
toFilter <- setdiff(seq_len(ncol(data2)), n)
cbind(data2[toKeep], data2[toFilter][sapply(data2[toFilter], nlevels)==3])
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V6
#1  B  B  D  C  B
#2  B  D  D  A  B
#3  D  E  B  A  B
#4  C  B  E  C  A
#5  D  D  A  D  E
#6  E  B  A  A  B
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
 data2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 8*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=8))
```